# React component not redraw when when props are updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Quick info to describe the context.
I am working to a tree component that receives as prop this kind of data model:

```
workfolder: [{
    label: "test",
    folders: [
        { label: "label 1", id: 1 },
        { label: "label 2", id: 2 },
        { label: "label 3", id: 3 }
    ]
}];
```

All data are stored in a Redux store.

The initial value is:

```
state: { workfolder: [] }
```

On mount i fetch for default values and merge the results to `workfolder` in the reducer and i get my tree drawn.

```
return {
  ...state,
  workfolder: results
}
```

When i click on one of the labels ( label 3 ) i fetch again for the sub-folders using the `id` and i get:

```
[{ label: "label 5", id: 5 },{ label: "label 5", id: 5 }]
```

At this point in the reducer i use a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-for-each) to loop deep into the state till i find the property matching the `id` of the element i clicked ( label 3 in this case ) and want to merge the sub-folders into a new folder attribute.

```
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.workfolder));

deepForEach( newState, (value, key, subject, path) => { 
    const isParentFolder = value === action.payload.parent;
    const hasNotFolders = !subject.folders;

    if( isParentFolder && hasNotFolders ) {

        subject.folders = action.payload.node

    }

} );
```

then i merge the new state in the store:

```
return {
    ...state,
    workfolder: newState
}
```

Following this way i get the store updated, but the component won't redraw.

NOTE: this is a dummy example. In real life i have to deal with a multi level nested object having only the `id` and a `string` containing the path of the attribute i want to modify in the store.
The example that i found in [the redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects) shows how to do that writing statically the merge...

Comment: How does your `connect` statement for the component look?

Comment: @IanLoubser This is the component that is wrapping the tree https://bitbucket.org/snippets/salvatore-me/7e5g8q

Comment: @IanLoubser and this is the component receiving the props https://bitbucket.org/snippets/salvatore-me/Lex48k

Comment: In line `27`, is `props.mappedWorkfolders` supposed to be passed to where `WorkFolder` component is called, or is it supposed to get that from the redux store? Your `mapStateToProps` defines a `workfolder` prop but not a `mappedWorkfolders`.

Comment: @IanLoubser the `workfolder`defined into `mapStateToProps`is useless actually.
I use `mappedWorkfolders` that are same values mapped with new keys from the parent component

Comment: I don't see where you actually read the content from the store though and where `mappedWorkfolders` should be defined in your `tree-wrapper.js` or passed to the `WorkFolder` component. If you say the store actually updates then the problem isn't with the code you posted above. Some more detail in your question would be appreciated :).